# check all checboxes on change of icheck using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, icheck

I'm trying to check/uncheck the `secondary checkboxes` on a check of the `primary checkbox`. But my jquery function is not working.

HTML code :

```
<table id="tab" class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="feature-1" class="ExtraCheckBox" type="checkbox"> Primary
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="feature-1" class="ChildCheckBox" type="checkbox"> Secondary
      <input name="feature-1" class="ChildCheckBox" type="checkbox"> Secondary
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery code :

```
$(document).on('change', '.ExtraCheckBox', function() {
  var checked = $(".ExtraCheckBox").closest('div.icheckbox_square-grey').hasClass("checked");
  console.log(checked);

  if (checked) {
    $("#tab > tr >td.ChildCheckBox").each(function() {
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
    });
  } else {
    $("#tab > tr >td.ChildCheckBox").each(function() {
      $(this).prop("checked", false);
    });
  }

});
```

Please find the js fiddle demo here : [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/yzyk2dqn/)

Any suggestions, please!

Comment: $(this).iCheck('check');  and $(this).iCheck('uncheck');  should help

Comment: https://github.com/fronteed/icheck#methods

Comment: @MehravishTemkar : checking the reference link .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
$('input.ExtraCheckBox').on('ifToggled', function(event){
  $('input.ChildCheckBox').iCheck('toggle');
});
```

Replace this code with your below code:

```
$(document).on('change', '.ExtraCheckBox', function() {
  var checked = $(".ExtraCheckBox").closest('div.icheckbox_square-grey').hasClass("checked");
  console.log(checked);
------- and so on
```

This is a custom library and it has its own event handling function. Use them.

Here is the link of that library and documentation: [link](http://icheck.fronteed.com/).

Comment: On click of checkbox the `checked ` class is adding to `div` tag. I have tried with your function it did not work :(

Comment: My pleasure  to help you

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use the callbacks and methods provided by icheck plugin.

```
jQuery('input').iCheck({
  checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-grey',
  radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
  increaseArea: '20%' // optional
});

$('.ExtraCheckBox').on('ifChecked', function() {

    $(".ChildCheckBox").iCheck('check');

});


$('.ExtraCheckBox').on('ifUnchecked', function() {

    $(".ChildCheckBox").iCheck('uncheck');

});
```

Hope this will help.
Check my fiddle version for this
http://jsfiddle.net/kajalc/6mmypwgs/

Answer (score 1):

This one's easy! None of your `<td>` elements *have* a class of `ChildCheckBox`.

Try this instead:

```
$(".ExtraCheckBox").on('click', function() {
  var checked = $(this).is(":checked");

  if (checked) {
    $("input.ChildCheckBox").each(function() {
      $(this).click();
    });
  } else {
    $("input.ChildCheckBox").each(function() {
      $(this).click();
    });
  }
});
```

See it working HERE http://jsbin.com/sawezogiju/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Your jquery code is working fine, check the updated fiddle link [here][1]

The issue is with the `iCheck` plugin. I think this is not responding with the `click` or `change` event.


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/yzyk2dqn/3/

Comment: @MayankPandeyz: For normal checkboxes my jquery function is working but not icheck checkboxes :(. Any suggestion what I can do?

Comment: i don't know what an iCheck checkbox is, but I'm guessing its a fancy looking one using CSS and labels and hiding the normal looking box. Inspect element, and you might find the markup is different from your source code!

Comment: @delboy1978uk: It's working for normal checkboxes but not for this icheck checkboxes. I'm trying to solve this

Comment: yup so inspect element, is the generated HTMLthe same as your HTML source?

Comment: Nope generated HTML is different than my HTML code.That why i m using closest div in my function

Comment: Exclude this iCheckbox thing and use scc to make checkbox look fancy and every thing will be fine.

Comment: OK so now, check an iCheck box manually, and inspect again, see what changed. That's what you need to click!

Comment: Plain old CSS3 checkboxes here if you're interested https://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/novBm

Answer (score 1):

Try something similar to this.

```
    $('input.ExtraCheckBox').on('ifClicked', function() {
    var checked=$(this).is(':checked');
    if(checked){
            $('.ChildCheckBox').iCheck('uncheck');
    }else{
            $('.ChildCheckBox').iCheck('check');
    }
});
```

Here is the updated link:[jsfiddle.net/yzyk2dqn/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/yzyk2dqn/9/)